# Distinguishing between my cousin's kids and my second cousin's parents

Tags: interpersonal-relations

Both of these are considered my "first cousin once removed". I not a fan of this ambiguity, and I don't like to explain relations in compounded terms (i.e. "my mother's brother" when the term "uncle" exists).

Is there an easier way to explain this difference without having to say "my cousin's son, not my second cousin's father?

I feel like the "once removed" being able to travel both directions in the ancestral chain is what causes this problem. If English had a term like "once added" to go down the chain, and changed "once removed" to only go up the chain, this issue wouldn't exist.

Does what I'm trying to describe exist?

Comment: The terminology for describing family relationships in English is not precise, and there is little you can do (short of spelling out the chain of relationship in detail) to make it more precise.  That's the way it is.  People will claim that a given form precisely means X, but, if true at all, it's only within a relatively small subculture.

Comment: I'm fine with small subculture answers. Spreading those around is how we create new words.

Comment: @Boom: But the broad thrust of development in the English language over centuries reflects the fact that Anglophones in general *neither need nor **want*** a large number of different words to describe "peripheral" family relationships (genetic and/or legal). All that matters to most of us is whether two people are such close (genetic) cousins that they shouldn't marry each other.

Comment: @jsw29 - Terms such as "my mother's brother" or "my mother's brother's child's child" are not that hard to understand (if you write them down).  They're just inconvenient.  But the language has not developed a consistent terminology to be more succinct yet still precise.

Comment: @Boom, short answer (which is not worthy of posting as an answer): no. Any terminology that could avoid the ambiguity you present would itself need to be explicitly introduced and explained, and that would make the communication as a whole more cumbersome than using the formulation that appears in the second paragraph of the question.

Comment: Notice that we don't even have unambiguus terms for some relatively close relations: brother-in-law can be either the brother of your spouse or husband of your sibling. If you want words for every type of family relationship, learn Warlpiri.

Answer (score -1):

No, unfortunately it doesn't exist because of the way it's derived.

First cousins share a grandparent, second cousins share a great-grandparent, third cousins share a great-great-grandparent, and so on. The "removed" indicates the number of generations separating the relatives.

So your **second** cousin's kids and parents are both your second cousins once removed. Your cousin's kids (I'm assuming first cousins) are your first cousins once removed. Their parents are too, but they are better known as aunts and uncles.

When you're describing first cousins, you can make a distinction based on whether your parent's siblings were the same or opposite sex. A **parallel** cousin is either your mother's sister's child or your father's brother's child (same gender siblings). A **cross** cousin is either your mother's brother's child or your father's sister's child (opposite gender siblings).

Comment: In my case, my cousin's kids are my mother's brother's grandkids. That would make them my cross first cousins once removed, right? My second cousin's parents are my mother's mother's sister's son (and his wife). Is that parallel or cross?

Comment: If the terms were to be used in the way that is presented here, it would be possible for X to be Y's **second** cousin once removed, while Y is X's **first** cousin once removed. Is there an authority that prescribes using the terms in this way, which is different from the one outlined in the question?

Answer (score -1):

I think a simpler way would to add a qualifyer of who is of the more senior generaton.

Why? Well: a first cousin once added is the {child of your cousin} or the {parent of your second cousin}, but consider that whatever you are to them, they are the other!!

So to say "they are my first cousin once added" suffixed with "i am the senior" would clarify that you mean your cousin's child/children; "I am the junior" would imply that they are your parents first cousin.

Comment: Your answer is not very coherent. Try and write it with the awareness that you are not the only one that is going to read it.